# LDAP properties binding fail

Tags: java, spring, spring-security, ldap

I have a bean with LDAP properties for authentication manager.

When I'm explicitly putting properties in there it does work, but when I started to use `.properties` file, it gives me an error.

> Failed to parse DN; nested exception is
>   org.springframework.ldap.core.TokenMgrError: Lexical error at line 1,
>   column 1. Encountered: "$" (36), after :

What do I do wrong?

```
@EnableWebSecurity
public class SecurityConfig {

    @Autowired
    public void configureGlobal(AuthenticationManagerBuilder auth) throws Exception {
        auth.ldapAuthentication()
            .userSearchFilter("${ldap.user_search_filter}")
            .userSearchBase("${ldap.user_search_base}")
            .groupSearchFilter("${ldap.group_search_filter}")
            .groupSearchBase("${ldap.group_search_base}")
            .groupRoleAttribute("${ldap.group_role_attribute}")
            .rolePrefix("${ldap.role_prefix}")
            .contextSource().ldif("${ldap.ldif_path}")
            .root("${ldap.root}");
    }
    .....
}
```

Comment: Because that is not the way it is supposed to work. Introduce variables in your configuration class and annotate with `@Value` or inject the `Environment` and use `env.getProperty(<property-name>);`.

Comment: @M.Deinum, when I tried to do that with `private static @Value("${ldap.user_search_filter}") String userSearchFilter;` it said **java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Either an LdapUserSearch or DN pattern (or both) must be supplied**

Comment: Because the field shouldn't be static.

Comment: @M.Deinum, and if I need to use it elsewhere?

Comment: Inject it there as well.